# How to apply the ocean modifier to get an animated object?

Tags: ocean-simulation

How to apply the ocean modifier to get an animated object, (not a static which have  froze in a single phase)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Export the mesh as an .mdd file format.
2. Remove any deformation modifiers on the object. Apply the Ocean modifier. The object needs to have same amount of vertices as while exported but strip down any animation on it.
3. Add Mesh Cache modifier and import the file into it:

   [image]
4. Now you baked the object's animation. Tadaa!
5. *You can also apply your modifiers as a shape key. To do this for every frame you need to do some scripting though.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I am testing this method right now, how to export the mesh as an .mdd file format? In the export menu I don't see this option: http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1JXECckl4T8kignDj5sfzkCEw6xQjk1

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Go into File > User Preferences > Addons > Category: Import-Export there you will find it as NewTech MDD Format

Comment: Thank you! Now when i deleted all modifiers (including ocean modifier) object has become a cube (as it was before ocean modifier). But when I use Mesh Cache - nothing happens. What i did wrong?
http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1YtSm7WuTLfcGxTkTTeHGeMv0W2ui

Comment: @MaximVelichkin You do remove only the deformation modifiers if there are any. Apply the Ocean. The object needs to have exact same amount of vertices so the MeshCache can animate them.