# Exporting Wave Modifier Animation into Unity

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, unity

I've made this controller with a wave modifier.

[image: Controller Animation]

What would be the best way to export it into Unity?

The animation doesn't need to be modifiable in Unity so i thought baking it to keyframes would be sufficient.  But i cant seem to work out how to do it.

Comment: Very nice first question! Welcome to the site.

Comment: I'm not a Unity user, but maybe this related question can help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/how-to-apply-the-ocean-modifier-to-get-an-animated-object