# How do I bake animation for exporting animation created by Wave modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, unity, .fbx

I've first created animation using armature for each and single leaf on my plant 3D model. But the wave modifier gives the same effect.

The thing is that once I export to .fbx, the animation is gone.

I've read several threads about this subject and none is giving a clear answer.

Is it possible to export the animation created by the modifier? I need to export for Unity3D.

[How to apply the ocean modifier to get an animated object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/how-to-apply-the-ocean-modifier-to-get-an-animated-object) - This one seems to give a clear answer except for stage 4: HOW DO I DO THAT?

[image]

Comment: Does Unity support a shape key animation?

Comment: Unity exports anything with shape keys as a skinned mesh rendered

Comment: @Jerryno can you shed any light?

Comment: The answer you reference works fine. Step 1. means you export the animation as an mdd file with the modifier still attached. Go to file-->export-->lightwave pointcache(mdd), name the file and save. You may need to go into preferences and enable the export to mdd file option. The rest of the answer is for when you want to animate in Blender. You should be able to import the saved file straight into Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You could try exporting alembic.. that would export the deforming geometry into an .abc file that can be ready by unity and other animation packages.

Comment: Hi Jason, Unity doesn't support .ABC files. Only .FBX for animation.

Comment: There are a few alembic importers for unity - but I just heard that the best one is written by a japanese company, unfortunately.. unless you can read japanese! :)

https://github.com/unity3d-jp/AlembicImporter

Answer (score 0):

I just took Jason's advice and exported as an .abc file.

You don't even need to apply the modifiers in Blender. If you are importing this in Keyshot like I did, make sure you check *Deformable Mesh* when the import box opens up.