# Can Wave modifier be exported as an animation

Tags: animation, modifiers, export

I need to do a wave animation on a simple oject and i do it with wave modifier.
I need the animated object exported in gltf format and used in three.js on the web.
When i apply the wave modifier it stops.
I need a way to attach the wave effect to the gltf.
Can i do this somehow?
[image: wave animation]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/how-to-apply-the-ocean-modifier-to-get-an-animated-object/30311#30311

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  When I do all that I end up with the same result.
But I now have the animation separately does this mean I need to import it separately in the web and put it over the unanimated object in three.js?