Coordinate multiple actions (bone animations) with multiple shape key animations, intended for Unity

Initial title: Make shrinkwrap animation suitable for export into Unity

Keywords, Key phrases
combining shape keys with armature animation, link shape key animation to one action animation, associate shape key animation with only one action
Quick answer
Skip the question and scroll down to the accepted answer. I got two Actions each paired with a distinct Shape Key animation, and they work in Unity!
Problem statement
Let the object have two Actions. Let each of those Actions be associated with a distinct Shape Key Animation. Both Shape Key Animations are made from exporting an mdd file, meaning there is one Shape Key for each frame.
As things are, there is no way to enforce the association between Actions and respective Shape Key Animations. Whichever Shape Key Animation is selected plays over whichever selected Action.
Question
How to handle this?
Is there a way to quickly and efficiently make drivers for a lot of Shape Keys comprising one animation that mdd provides upon import? So that one driver corresponds to one animation.
Is NLA gonna help me?
Is scripting the answer?
Original post (background)
I am new to Blender and would appreciate your help.
I made an animation of an elastic bag deforming in response to the movement of its content. And now I don't know how to save its deformation in an animation and export it into Unity.
This is how I made the animation. Two icospheres are parented to bones, which are animated using the keyframes. One of the icospheres, let's call it primary, has a Bool Modifier set to Union with the other. A cube, let's call it wrapper, of proper size and subdivision, has a ShrinkWrap Modifier with the primary icosphere as a target.
The closest thing I found to saving deformation in an animation was Shape Key keyframing. You make many Shape Keys and specify how they influence the mesh with keyframes.
But my animation is rather long, and making all the ShapeKeys for the ShrinkWrap by hand is not feasible.
Another option is cloth simulation, I guess? Its complexity prevents me from investigating further.
I would be grateful to learn either how to save and export the deformations of a wrapper in an animation, or how to make the same animation without the ShrinkWrap all together if it means reliable export.
Partial solution
Shape Keys seem to work. Following the advice regarding mdd here, you can make an FBX with one animation that will work in Unity as intended. Provided that the target mesh has an Action animation of the same duration that the Shape Key animation.
The catch is that Shape Keys exist as things entirely different from Actions, see this. They will play over every animation. Which ruins one of my two Actions.
If only you could choose when to play Shape Key animations relative to the Actions.
But, as far as my research shows with more than one Action animation, you can't control which Shape Key animation plays over it without dabbling in NLA, or scripts, or drivers.
The problem is, all the approaches I've found fail if ShapeKeys in the animation are plentiful. Which is exactly the case when mdd's are exported into objects.
Possible solutions

The script here will add an 'animatable' custom property to the target object for each ShapeKey from chosen animation. Wasteful?

Drivers (1, 2) seem to be used only when the ShapeKey animation consists of changing one ShapeKey.
Though, in this video you can see how multiple ShapeKeys can be linked to one driver. I imagine you can automate the process for the situation mdd's land you in.

NLA doesn't seem to provide a solution (link) and 'bake shape keys together with animation in nla blender' search brings me to this promising video that I haven't watched yet



https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/how-to-apply-the-ocean-modifier-to-get-an-animated-object/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/is-it-possible-to-export-object-from-blender-with-modifiers-and-use-them-in-exte

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you for the links! They show that dynamic Blender modifiers are Blender-specific and cannot be exported by themselves. They show that mesh deformations can be stored in a mdd file. I followed some of the links present in posts you mentioned, and found one to be exceptionally useful https://blenderartists.org/t/bake-cloth-to-game-engine/657339/3

Sadly, the solution provided is limited to ONE ShapeKey animation.

Modifier based and deformation based animations are hard if not impossible to export properly. Most of the export options are based on mesh caches, which are a heavy series of meshes, one per frame, and inadequate for most game engine purposes. I'm not much into game engines, but what you should be doing is either making a base mesh you can run a simulation on directly in the engine, or find a way to make your animation armature based

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you for your suggestions! After further research (that I've documented in this post), as of Blender 2.81 I don't think coordinating actions and shape keys is worth it.

I am sorry in advance for how long the answer is, but I want to be as thorough as possible, considering how hard it was to find a comprehensive answer anywhere.
The basis of my solution is this wonderful video
Prerequisites
I am new to Blender, and don't know what matters, so I'll specify everything I can think of. Today is 27th of september 2024, I am using Blender 2.81a and Unity 2022.3.46f1. All the actions I made are shielded. I select the object and export to FBX with the following settings

Thanks to this wonderful video you'll learn that

Actions and ShapeKeys live on different NLA strips, but on the same timeline 
When NLA track comes with multiple Actions, Unity automatically cuts Actions out based on their first and last frames, and packs them neatly into clips for you to use.
I don't know how to make it less messy, but the first two clips work for me

And, what matters most, Unity will grab whatever ShapeKey animation is below the Action in the NLA editor, and will combine them in a clip!

Solution
To make it work, you should be careful with the mdd process, since it stores how the mesh is deforming relative to the Basis Shape Key. I will describe the steps I took to store two different deformations corresponding to two different Actions for one ShrinkWrapped mesh, call it wrapper. Each action moves other objects that the wrapper has to wrap. Think of the wrapper as an extremely elastic bag around some moving rocks.

Select the wrapper and temporarily disable or delete the Shrinkwrap modifier. Ideally the wrapper should have no modifiers now.
In object data properties, make sure that the wrapper has no Shape Keys and click on the plus icon, making the Basis Shape Key, which will become a reference for deformations to come.
Return the Shrinkwrap modifier
Select the object that has to be wrapped. You should now be able to select the first Action. Click 'Push down' to make it into an NLA track and unlink it from the object.
On the timeline, make sure that start and end frames correspond to first and last frame of the first Action inside NLA. Press play on the Timeline or spacebar to make sure.
Do the mdd thing. Select wrapper only, export mdd, open Dope Sheet Shape Key Editor, with wrapper selected import mdd, choose proper name for the Key Action that gets created.
With Shape Key animation you just imported still being active, click 'Push down' to make it into an NLA Key track.
Remove the Shrinkwrap modifier from the wrapper once again. Press play, to make sure that the deformation data got imported correctly for the first Action. Return the Shrinkwrap modifier.
Select the object that has to be wrapped. Select the second Action. Click 'Push down'.
Inside NLA editor move the second Action into the same Track with the first Action, somewhere after it. You can see how I did it in the second screenshot of Prerequisites.
On the timeline, make sure that start and end frames correspond to first and last frame of the second Action inside NLA. Press play to make sure that the animation is what you want.
Do the mdd thing and push the resulting Shape Key Animation into NLA. Move it into the same Track with the first Key Action. Align it with the second Action. In my case, rotate.001 is in the same Track with chaotic, and is aligned with IcosphereAction
Remove the SrhinkWrap modifier and see if the animation is correct
With the wrapper selected, export as FBX (copy my settings if you want) and import the FBX as a new asset into Unity.

